# What am I doing wrong? Derivative of pedal

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $\gamma$ be a unit speed curve $\gamma : I \to \mathbb R^2$.

The pedal is given by $P (s) = (\gamma (s) \cdot N(s)) N(s)$.

I tried to calculate the derivative as follows:

$$ P' = (\gamma N)' N + (\gamma N) N' = (\gamma' N + \gamma N')N + (\gamma N) N'$$

Then substituting $\gamma' = T, T' = \kappa N$ and $N' = - \kappa T$ I got

$$ P' = (TN + \gamma (-\kappa)T)N + (\gamma N) (-\kappa)T$$

Since $TN = 0$,

$$ P' = -\kappa (\gamma T)N -\kappa (\gamma N) T$$

But I should be getting

$$ P' = -\kappa (\gamma T)N +(\gamma N) T$$

(according to page 36 in for example [this book](https://books.google.com/books?id=rhq3YCguBOUC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false))

I did it 3 times and get the same result.

> Please could somebody point out my mistake to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xipan Xiao has already provided an example that resolves the question; you can also resolve it by checking the scaling behaviour. The scaled unit speed curve $\tilde\gamma(t)=c\gamma(t/c)$ with $c\in\mathbb R^+$ has $\tilde T(t)=T(t/c)$ and $\tilde N(t)=N(t/c)$ and thus $\tilde P(t)=cP(t/c)$ and $\tilde P'(t)=P(t/c)$, so with $\tilde\kappa=\kappa/c$ your result scales correctly and the "should be getting" result doesn't.

Comment: I'm not quite clear on what you call "scaling": e.g. if $\gamma$ is the unit circle, $\gamma (t) = (\cos t, \sin t)$ then the scaled circle, say of radius $2$, would be $\widetilde{\gamma} (t) = (2 \cos t, 2 \sin t) = c \gamma (t)$. Not $c\gamma ({t\over c})$. What am I missing?

Comment: @astudent: Your $\tilde\gamma$ isn't a unit speed curve. I defined the scaling such that the scaled curve still has unit speed, and thus your result applies to it. If you wouldn't call this "scaling", never mind, you can call it something else -- the important part is the definition $\tilde\gamma(t)=c\gamma(t/c)$ that I gave.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I understand: we need the curve to be unit speed because we have defined the pedal in terms of unit speed curves. It does make me wonder if it's necessary to do this or if we couldn't define pedal for any curve.

Comment: @astudent: Yes, you can define the pedal for any curve (if it's as differentiable as you're assuming $\gamma$ to be) by reparametrizing the curve by its arc length, yielding a unit speed curve. But your entire calculation was based on the Frenet–Serret frame and formulas, and thus on unit speed; the equations you used don't hold if the prime doesn't refer to differentiation with respect to arc length.

Comment: Thank you joriki for patiently explaining this to me, you helped me a lot!

Comment: I think you just resolved my other question too: if the curve is unit speed then we can apply Frenet Serret to the parallel...

Answer (score 2):

At least, if we choose the curve to be the circle of radius 0.5, your result is correct and the "should be getting" result is wrong.